# Gstreamer alsasrc element error

Tags: camera, streaming, gstreamer, microphone, alsa

I installed gst-plugins-base-1.8.1 clearly.

Download from
https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/modules/
and

```
./configure
make
sudo make install
```

And alsasrc elemenet is in that base plugin.
I check it from
https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/data/doc/gstreamer/head/gst-plugins-base-plugins/html/

But when I run this

```
gst-launch alsasrc device=hw:1 ! audioconvert ! audioresample  ! alawenc ! rtppcmapay ! udpsink host=192.168.20.26 port=5001
```

I get this error

```
ERROR: pipeline could not be constructed: no element "alsasrc".
```

How can I should do??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first - you used gst-launch and not gst-launch-1.0 .. second - did you compile also the [gstreamer core](https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/modules/gstreamer.html)? The -base depends on this.. you need to have it compiled..

Then you have to check the version if you really are on that 1.8 and not on some system default gstreamer (I guess you are on linux/mac):

gst-launch-1.0 --version

By default on Linux the gstreamer is make installed into /usr/local/ prefix.. which is picked with PATH etc.. maybe you have to also set GST_PLUGIN_BASE and LD_LIBRARY_PATH and PATH in order to compile gst-plugins-base on top of gstreamer (core)..

check it and update question.. you may write me a comment that you did

Comment: Hi, @otopolsky Thanks for answering me, and I checked what was my fault. I ignored PATH. Just command ./configure. So I reinstalled following here, linuxfromscratch.org/blfs/view/svn/index.html And finally it works with gst-launch-1.0, Thank you.